# I do not have any error but Data not getting inserted in table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database- "contact.db" with a table name "contact". I have id, name, email and mobile number fields(id is autogenerated). The application is running successfully, also when I enter all the details and click on save the toast is displaying "data inserted", But if I export the database to the local computer and see the table the data is not inserted there.

**Mainactivity.java**

```
package org.pankaj.com.contactmanager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
 Button insert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        insert= findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddNewContact.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

**Addnewcontact.java**

```
package org.pankaj.com.contactmanager;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddNewContact extends AppCompatActivity {



    EditText name,mobile_number,email;
    Button save;

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_contact);

        databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        name=findViewById(R.id.etName);
        mobile_number= findViewById(R.id.etMobileNumber);
        email=findViewById(R.id.etEmailId);

        save=findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Boolean result=databaseHelper.insertData(name.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(mobile_number.getText().toString()),email.getText().toString());

                if(result)
                    Toast.makeText(AddNewContact.this,"data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                else
                    Toast.makeText(AddNewContact.this,"data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Databasehelper.java**

```
package org.pankaj.com.contactmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="contact.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="contact";



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
      //SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase(); // used only for database creation
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,MOBILE_NUMBER INTEGER,EMAIL TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("commit;");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);


    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, int mobile_number, String email){

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("NAME",name);
        contentValues.put("MOBILE_NUMBER",mobile_number);
        contentValues.put("EMAIL",email);

        long result= db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

      // db.execSQL("commit;");

        if(result == -1)
            return  false;
        else
            return true;

    }




}
```

Comment: Close the db after inserting the value - `db.close();`

Comment: :) thanks a lot, such a blunder